# How to convert url of html page to pdf in java using iText & flying saucer?

Tags: java, flying-saucer, html-to-pdf, xhtmlrenderer

I've just downloaded xhtmlrenderer and iText jar files. I can make pdf files by using these jars.

What I exactly want is: 
I need to create pdf if I give one valid URL (say "`https://xhtmlrenderer.dev.java.net/news.html`") in the place of "inputFile". Is it possible with flying saucer and iText?

If yes, please guide me to achieve this.

Also, when I'm trying to run the below code, I'm getting error: stream closed

```
import java.io.*;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

public class FirstDoc {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws IOException, DocumentException {
        String inputFile = "samples/sql.html";
        String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
        String outputFile = "firstdoc.pdf";
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocument(url);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os);

        os.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code contains `com.lowagie`. That is an ancient version of iText. Please use `com.itextpdf` iText.

Answer (score 2):

Yes... this probably won't work as the page being requested isn't xhtml but this should do the trick:

```
import java.io.*;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

public class FirstDoc {

public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
    String url= "http://xhtmlrenderer.java.net/news.html";

    String outputFile = "firstdoc.pdf";
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(url);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);

    os.close();
}
}
```

The stream closed error occurs when the file you're requesting isn't found. The 'samples' folder must exist in the project in your workspace or wherever it is that you're running your application from

Comment: My HTML contains '&' in between text. How to handle that

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question